# "Office document"/"PDF" content is not appearing in SharePoint Online (Office 365) search

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-online, pdf, image, sharepoint-search

I am working on "SharePoint online". I have restored the site and everything is working fine except Search. Even search is also working fine but not including the result of Office document, PDF document and not returning any type of result from document library which I am using. what I am getting is "aspx" pages (views and Disp/Edit/New forms) and folders etc.

- I did Googling a-lot but not found any of the way to configure the search on SharePoint Online.
- I need to search the searchable PDF and non-searchable PDF.
- I am using OCR (On my on-Prems SharePoint) for non-searchable PDF and Images to make them searchable (Using web service calling from farm solution). How can I achieve the same on SharePoint online.
- I am getting below icon for PDF in document library and search result. I don't know which image is this.
  [image: Unknown PDF icon]

Please help or share if you guys aware about the above cases. Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?